# What's the encrypted code?

Tags: lateral-thinking

What is the code in:

> eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeooeeeeeeeeeeeeeppeeeeeiiiieeeeeooeeeeeeeeeeppppppppeeiiiieeeeeooeeooooeeeeeeeppeeeeeeeeeeeeooooeeeeooooeeeppeeeeeiiiieeeeeooeebbbbbbboobbbbbbeeiiiieeeeeooeebbeeeeeooeeppeeeeeiiiieeeeeooeebbbbbbbbbbbppbbeeiiiieeeeeoooobbbbbbbbbbbppbbeeiiiieeeeeeeeebbeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeebbbbbbbbbbbbbbbe

You don't really have to read the entire thing, you have to think differently

Clue 1:

> It is slightly unorganized, make sure to enlarge the size!

Clue 2:

> It is a word, but not from the letters is the code

Clue 3:

> A four letter word

Comment: It seems to me like this puzzle might be very browser-dependent and completely unsolvable on certain systems. Have you checked whether it's doable on other systems in the way you intend?

Comment: length of 329 + "unorganized" suggests a 47x7 grid. Doing that reveals some mildly suspicious things. E.g. repeating patterns for letters.

Comment: There are 7 "iiii" strings located resonably away from each other.

Comment: Is it related to ASCII art ?

Comment: Time to provide the 2nd clue.

Comment: Time to provide the next clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution is inspired by @AlphaLife!

Here's how I arranged the letters:

> [image]

Then,

> We can make out the shapes of the letters b, i, t, and e.

Thus, I think the answer is...

> **BITE!**

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this is worthy of an answer.
By colour coding the letters and varying the  grid size,

> [image]

This happens...

> [image]

Maybe someone else can build up on this...

Comment: I see some letters, these letters are h, t, i and e.

Comment: Im not sure if its an h as much as a b

Comment: Maybe there is an o because of the yellow things outside?

Comment: Associates to Berkley SETI encoding.